# How to make a circle move and spin at the same time?

Tags: css

Basically, the circle moves from left to right spinning like a tire. I tried applying transform rotate 360 but it doesn't work.

html:

```
 <div class="circle"></div>
```

css:

```
 .circle{
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   background-color: green;
   border-radius: 10px;
   -webkit-animation:movespin 4s ease-in-out;
   animation:movespin 4s ease-in-out;
 }

 @-webkit-keyframes movespin {
   0% {
     transform: translateX(0px);
     transform:rotate(360deg);
   }
   100% {
    transform: translateX(900px);
    transform:rotate(360deg);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put them together.

```css
.circle {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-animation: movespin 4s ease-in-out;
  animation: movespin 4s ease-in-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes movespin {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(900px) rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Comment: One of those `rotate` properties needs to be `0deg` :) But you're right, combine the transformations.

Comment: @Scott you're right. I found that and I was editing the original question.

Comment: I've edited to include OP's line of HTML, making the code a runnable snippet. Feel free to rollback this edit if you feel inclined :)

Comment: You might want to mention in the answer the identical `rotate` properties are an issue since the OP had that in the question. You're call though :)

Comment: One other thing: Editing a question is great for "neatening up", but generally it's not a good idea to change the original question's code. OP specifically mentioned that their *"transform rotate 360 doesn't work"*, but now it *does*, creating a conflict.  This could cause confusion for future readers. Instead, consider correcting it in *your* solution, noting what you've changed.

Comment: @TylerRoper OK, I agree with that. Thanks again :)

Comment: @NoobTW yep I think that the proposed edit was better suited as an answer (this answer... your answer)